# Target encoding multiple columns in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table.

```
id col1 col2 col3 col4  target
1    A    B  A    101   1
2    B    B  A    191   1
3    A    B  A     81   0 
4    C    B  C     67   1
5    B    C  C      3   0
```

I want to target encode every column except `col4`.

**Expected Output:**

```
e1    e2     e3     target
0.5   0.75   0.667    1
0.5   0.75   0.667    1
0.5   0.75   0.667    0
1.0   0.75   0.5      1
0.5   0.00   0.5      0
```

**EDIT:**
For each column of `col1`, `col2`, `col3` I want to get the target encodings.

For example, in col3, A appears 3 times and 2/3 times it has a target of 1. thus the encoding will be 0.667 for A. Similarly for C it will be 0.5 in col3.

I've tried something like this one for one column:

```
encodings = df.groupby('col1')['target'].mean().reset_index()
df = df.merge(encodings, how = 'left', on = 'col1')
df.drop('col1', axis = 1, inplace = TRUE)
```

Comment: Apologises - I've updated the output. Hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: For col3, A appears 3/5 times so it will calculate to 0.6  for e3.  C appears 2/5 times, so it will calculate to 0.4 for e3. Same logic applies for col2 and col1.

Comment: Note that the calculation is fully independent from `target` ;)

Comment: I apologize I asked the question incorrectly and updated the example output. It is actually dependent on the target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

###### update after clarification:

You need to use the same approach as in your original attempt, but using `map`

```
df.update(df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]
          .apply(lambda s: s.map(df['target'].groupby(s).mean()))
          )
```

output:

```
   id col1  col2      col3  col4  target
0   1  0.5  0.75  0.666667   101       1
1   2  0.5  0.75  0.666667   191       1
2   3  0.5  0.75  0.666667    81       0
3   4  1.0  0.75       0.5    67       1
4   5  0.5   0.0       0.5     3       0
```

###### older answer prior to OP clarification

IIUC, you want to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the normalized [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].apply(lambda s: s.map(s.value_counts(normalize=True)))
```

output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0   0.4   0.8   0.6
1   0.4   0.8   0.6
2   0.4   0.8   0.6
3   0.2   0.8   0.4
4   0.4   0.2   0.4
```

###### updating the data in place:

```
df.update(df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]
          .apply(lambda s: s.map(s.value_counts(normalize=True)))
          )
```

updated DataFrame:

```
   id col1 col2 col3  col4  target
0   1  0.4  0.8  0.6   101       1
1   2  0.4  0.8  0.6   191       1
2   3  0.4  0.8  0.6    81       0
3   4  0.2  0.8  0.4    67       1
4   5  0.4  0.2  0.4     3       0
```

Answer (score 1):

You may can try with `transform` with for loop

```
l = [df.groupby(col)['target'].transform('mean') for col in ['col1','col2','col3']]
out = pd.concat(l + [df.target],keys = ['e1','e2','e3','target'],axis=1)
out
Out[247]: 
    e1    e2        e3  target
0  0.5  0.75  0.666667       1
1  0.5  0.75  0.666667       1
2  0.5  0.75  0.666667       0
3  1.0  0.75  0.500000       1
4  0.5  0.00  0.500000       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). For each column - calculate the average of `target` grouped by this column:

```py
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].apply(lambda s: s.map(df['target'].groupby(s).mean()))
```

```py
   col1  col2      col3
0   0.5  0.75  0.666667
1   0.5  0.75  0.666667
2   0.5  0.75  0.666667
3   1.0  0.75  0.500000
4   0.5  0.00  0.500000
```

---

If you also want to have a `target` column, you can just use [`.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) at the end:

```py
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].apply(lambda s: s.map(df['target'].groupby(s).mean())).assign(target=df['target'])
```

```py
   col1  col2      col3  target
0   0.5  0.75  0.666667       1
1   0.5  0.75  0.666667       1
2   0.5  0.75  0.666667       0
3   1.0  0.75  0.500000       1
4   0.5  0.00  0.500000       0
```

> *Note:* `.apply()` and `.transform()` give identical results here. You can replace one with the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.concat([df1[col].map(pd.crosstab(df1[col],df1.target,normalize='index')[1]) for col in ['col1','col2','col3']],axis=1).join(df1.target)
    
      col1  col2      col3  target
    0   0.5  0.75  0.666667       1
    1   0.5  0.75  0.666667       1
    2   0.5  0.75  0.666667       0
    3   1.0  0.75  0.500000       1
    4   0.5  0.00  0.500000       0
```